# Do i need to Model.init() after i define the model? sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I couldn't find anything about having to Model.init() after defining a Model, i think i am doing something wrong or maybe i have to do it using **sequelize** instead of **sequelize-typescript**. In the piece of code im trying to use class-transformer (and failing xd) so just ignore it.. So what happens is that **sequelize** complains that my Model is not defined and to solve it i put the Model.init() on it, is it correct what im doing?

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '@shared/infra/sequelize/index';
import { Table, Model, Column } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

@Table({ tableName: 'acesso_api' })
export default class User extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true })
  id: number;

  @Column
  nome: string;

  @Column
  @Exclude()
  password: string;

  @Column
  @Exclude()
  password_hash: string;

  @Column
  cliente: string;

  @Column({ defaultValue: 0 })
  @Exclude()
  admin: number;
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nome: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
    },
    password_hash: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    },
    cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
    },
    admin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'acesso_api',
    sequelize,
  },
);
```

By the way this is how my default connection is settled( and yes the sequelize-typescript don't have any problem finding the models):

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export default new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.HOST,
  username: process.env.POLO_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: 'some_DB',
  repositoryMode: true,
  models: [`${__dirname}./src/modules/**/infra/sequelize/entities/*.ts`],
  port: 3306,
  define: {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  },
});
```

And this is the bug message that is given to me if i dont Model.init() it (the injection message is because of tsyringe so just ignore it):

```
Server started at port 8080
Error: Cannot inject the dependency "userRepository" at position #0 of "AuthenticateUserService" constructor. Reason:
    User has not been defined
    at /home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:290:23
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at InternalDependencyContainer.construct (/home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:266:34)
    at InternalDependencyContainer.resolve (/home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:105:33)
    at /home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/src/modules/users/infra/http/controllers/SessionController.ts:10:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/src/modules/users/infra/http/controllers/SessionController.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/src/modules/users/infra/http/controllers/SessionController.ts:4:12)
    at create (/home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/src/modules/users/infra/http/controllers/SessionController.ts:20:16)
[INFO] 10:43:09 Restarting: /home/leandro/Documents/Projetos/api/src/shared/infra/sequelize/index.ts has been modified
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/d1020fa3-ae78-4f6c-ae7f-2374628c237b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out, its exactly like that. 'sequelize-typescript' does not init the models you create automatically so you have to do it manually, and this is good actually because you can choose when you want to init it. Currently i am working on a application that require multiple database connections and being able to init the models whenever you want is just saving the day for me.